# mid-2011 iMac will not update DHCP address

Tags: network, imac, ethernet

I realize mid-2011 iMac is aging out, but it is what I have.  It is running 10.13.6 (High Sierra).  I recently installed a Netgear GS305E between our cable modem and the computer.  The Netgear Switch Discovery app for Mac cannot locate the switch even though the Mac is plugged directly into it.  The other computers on the switch have all been updated without issue.  I have tried to manually set an IP address (increment the address used by another PC on the switch) but the modem does not recognize the address. I also tried to refresh the DHCP lease (multiple times).  What steps can I take to get the iMac back to DHCP addressing?

Comment: I also tried to to frefresh DHCP lease (multiple times).

Comment: Please include within your question a screen capture of 'System Preferences… > Network > Ethernet > Advanced… > TCP/IP`.

Comment: Please switch the Wi-Fi off within your network configuration you want to work on Ethernet.